# IE button inside label with checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, button, label

I have a code like this:

```
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="f6c9677c-309c-446c-9f78-757467ec7adc">
    <label for="f6c9677c-309c-446c-9f78-757467ec7adc">
        <span> Testigos de la Valoracion </span>
        <button disabled>Button</button>
    </label>
</li>
```

The problem is that the button is disabled and in IE (v11, latest) when I click on it, the checkbox gets activated. **I cannot change the structure.**

I have tried capturing the event and preventing it from propagating and default behaviour. Nothing works.

In all other browsers it works normally: click on a disabled button does nothing.

Comment: Is there a reason to have a button within the `<label>` element? ( I know that you cannot change the structure )

Comment: Not really. But I cannot change that :S In other browsers works well

Comment: Well, to fix it simply, you only have to do `disabled="disabled"` in that <button> element.

Comment: it doesn't work. Already tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible work around might be preventing the default event if the target is button:

```js
document.querySelector('label').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(e.target.nodeName == 'BUTTON')
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<li>
  <input type="checkbox" id="f6c9677c-309c-446c-9f78-757467ec7adc">
  <label for="f6c9677c-309c-446c-9f78-757467ec7adc">
    <span> Testigos de la Valoracion </span>
    <button disabled>Button</button>
  </label>
</li>
```

Comment: Didn't work exactly as the nodeName was 'LABEL' sometimes, but the idea of preventing events when clicking the label was what helped me. Thank you

Comment: @SergioTx, you are most welcome.... you are right, that's why IE does not fancy us (the developer).......

Answer (score 0):

```
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="f6c9677c-309c-446c-9f78-757467ec7adc">
    <label for="f6c9677c-309c-446c-9f78-757467ec7adc">
        <span> Testigos de la Valoracion </span>


    </label>
     <button disabled="disabled">Button</button>
</li>
```

Comment: I cannot change the structure

Comment: But what's the reason behind using button inside label block ?

Comment: If possible you can use div in stead of label . It will also solve your problem :|

Comment: Hmmm. Not my code. But it is because of a library that has a getTitle() and it puts everything inside a label. Someone added the button there.

Comment: But problem is label is for checkbox . So in IE its thinking whole block with label as a single block and whenever clicked on button it considering it click on checkbox :/  .IE the  Smartest browser you know :P

Comment: I know the logic of what IE thinks. But nobody else seems to think that way :P

Answer (score 0):

Since you are unable to change the structure, you can use JavaScript to prevent button behavior. Even disabled ones. Or, - fortunately - use CSS to work around that: [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

```
label button[disabled] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Does it do the job for you?

***Note***: It works only for IE11 or higher.